# Why my socketio is not connecting with my socketio-client?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

i am working on a chatapp project that needs a real time chatting so i have used socketio in my server side which is written in nodejs and than used socketio-client in my main chatapp react-native project.

But now a problem is coming my socket is not initializing. I'm not able to connect my server with my main app. I am using socketio and socketio client my both the socket version are same 4.5.1 but it's not even connecting. I have tried to use old version of socket but its also not working and I have also tried to change my localhost port to 4000 but it's also not working.

My server code:

```
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

require('./src/config/database')
const user_routes = require('./src/user/users.routes');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.use('/User', user_routes)
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');


  socket.on('send_message',(data)=>{
    console.log("received message in server side",data)
    io.emit('received_message',data)
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
  
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log( `Server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

My app socketservice file code:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const SOCKET_URL = 'http://localhost:3000'

class WSService {

    initializeSocket = async () => {
        try {

            this.socket = io(SOCKET_URL, {
                transports: ['websocket']
            })
            console.log("initializing socket", this.socket)

            this.socket.on('connect', (data) => {
                console.log("=== socket connected ====")
            })

            this.socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
                console.log("=== socket disconnected ====")
            })

            this.socket.on('error', (data) => {
                console.log("socekt error", data)
            })

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("scoket is not inialized", error)
        }
    }

    emit(event, data = {}) {
        this.socket.emit(event, data)
    }
    
    on(event, cb) {
        this.socket.on(event, cb)
    }

    removeListener(listenerName) {
        this.socket.removeListener(listenerName)
    }

}

const socketServcies = new WSService()

export default socketServcies
```

Where I have marked it should be connected = true but it's false in the dev console I have done console log so check that it's connecting or not and I can see that it's not connecting. How to make it connect?

There is no error in my app or server I have checked many times and my server is also running when I am running my app.

Comment: Try not specifying the URL: `this.socket = io()`

Comment: @Codebling so than what should i use?

Comment: @Codebling  check my answered question

Comment: Just to follow up, doing `io()` makes it automatically connect to the host from the address bar. It should automatically work. That way you avoid having to set up different environments for dev and production, or reconfigure if you change the hostname.

Comment: @Codebling i am confused can you pls write the code and answer?

Comment: ok added an answer, I am not sure it is helpful since you already know the solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your front and back runs in localhost. [The documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/#from-the-same-domain) says that if the front-end is in the same domain as the back-end, you don't need to use the URL. Since you have the `options` parameter declared, you can use the default argument `window.location` in first place:

```
class WSService {

    initializeSocket = async () => {
        try {

            this.socket = io(window.location, {
                transports: ['websocket']
            })
            console.log("initializing socket", this.socket)

            this.socket.on('connect', (data) => {
                console.log("=== socket connected ====")
            })

            this.socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
                console.log("=== socket disconnected ====")
            })

            this.socket.on('error', (data) => {
                console.log("socekt error", data)
            })

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("scoket is not inialized", error)
        }
    }

    emit(event, data = {}) {
        this.socket.emit(event, data)
    }
    
    on(event, cb) {
        this.socket.on(event, cb)
    }

    removeListener(listenerName) {
        this.socket.removeListener(listenerName)
    }

}
```

Comment: not working dear do you need my repo? its directly saying scoket is not inialized that means its wrong TypeError: Cannot set property hostname of [object WorkerLocation] which has only a getter

Comment: Oops, it's because window.location is an object, but the parameter must be a string. Try `window.location.toString()` instead of `window.location`.

Comment: we were going wrong check my answered question

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question
The problem was i was using android emulator and android in an emulator can't connect to localhost you need to use the proxy ip so when i add `http://10.0.2.2:3000` in `const SOCKET_URL = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000'` than its working fine
credit goes to gorbypark who told me this in discord

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the host/port for socket-io to connect to. It can figure it out on its own.

Per [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#iourl), it tries to connect to `window.location` if no URL is specified as an argument.

So instead of

```
            this.socket = io(SOCKET_URL, {
                transports: ['websocket']
            })
```

Just do

```
            this.socket = io()
```

I am not sure it works with other arguments. You could try like this

```
            this.socket = io(undefined, {
                transports: ['websocket']
            })
```